# How to mount Azure File Share as Volume for Container Group using docker-compose?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-storage, azure-files

I want to mount Azure File Share as volume from my Docker-Compose. The example I have from Microsoft is to use [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files#deploy-container-and-mount-volume---cli). How can I achieve the same, but with `docker-compose`?

The following `docker-compose` does not work for me as I am unable to install `azure_file` driver in my Windows environment, which has also been deprecated.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: flask-app
    container_name: flask-app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - code:/code
    depends_on:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis

volumes:
  code:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: myacishare
      storage_account_name: mystorageaccount
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python app.py
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis

app = Flask(__name__)
redis = Redis(host="redis", port=6379)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    redis.incr("hits")
    return "This Compose/Flask demo has been viewed %s time(s)." % redis.get("hits")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

**requirements.txt**

```
flask
redis
```

Comment: Do you still work on this issue? If not, please delete it. If yes, I can give some advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker plugin install docker4x/cloudstor:azure-v17.03.0-ce --grant-all-permissions --alias azure CLOUD_PLATFORM=AZURE AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT="[account name]" AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY="[access key]"
```

this version of cloudstor works for me, but you can try other options from https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/docker4x/cloudstor/tags

answer from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-containers-volume-logging-drivers#using-your-own-volume-or-logging-driver